# How to calculate the ways to paint n different balls with exact c different colors?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, combinations, dynamic-programming

I came across a problem recently.

Suppose f(n,c) = the ways to paint n different balls with exact c different colors. (pay attention that all c colors have to be used at least once and every ball is considered different)

For this problem, I need to calculate all f(n,c) where 1<=c<=n<=S mod 1e9+7.

For orginal problem, S=200. So I made a O(S^3) solution like below:

```
typedef long long ll;
ll MOD=1e9+7;
#define S 200
ll C[S+2][S+2],pows[S+2][S+2],sel[S+2][S+2];
ll sel_(int n,int c)
{
    ll ans=0; int cur=-1;
    for(int i=c;i>=1;i--)
    {
        cur*=-1;
        ans+=cur*pows[i][n]%MOD*C[c][i]%MOD;
        ans%=MOD;
    }
    return ans;
}
int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<=S;i++)
    {
        C[i][0]=1; pows[i][0]=1;
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        C[i][j]=(C[i-1][j-1]+C[i-1][j])%MOD;
        for(int j=1;j<=S;j++)
        pows[i][j]=pows[i][j-1]*i%MOD;
    }
    sel[0][0]=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=S;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++) sel[i][j]=sel_(i,j);
    }
    //the answers are stored in sel
}
```

But I suppose there might be some ways to solve it in O(S^2). How can I achieve that?

Comment: To ask for improvement of working code you are better off asking at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the question is about better algorithm so I believe it is more suited for here

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical application for the [inclusion exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Let us denote by `f(n, k)` the number of ways to color n balls with **up to** k colors(out of the original c colors) and by `g(n, k)` the number of ways to color n balls with **exactly** k colors(out of the original c colors). Then `g(n, k) = f(n, k) - f(n, k - 1) + f(n, k - 2) - ...`. Counting the ways to color the balls with up to k colors is much, much easier - in fact the formula is very simple, but I will leave it to you to figure out what it is.

And finally the number you are looking for is g(n, c), which can be computed using the formula above.

Comment: As I know, f(n,c)=c^n. Right? But I think your formula might be wrong. Since g(2,2)=f(2,2)-f(2,1)=3 which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Actually `f(2,1) = 2` and `f(2, 2) = 4` using your formula(which btw is correct)

Comment: Why coloring 2 balls with only 1 color will give 2 ways?

Comment: @newbie sorry my answer is misleading a bit here. f(n, k) is the number of ways to color n balls with up to k colors out of the original c colors. I will fix that. So f(2, 1) is 2 because you can color them with any of the two colors

Comment: In fact I wrote like this myself, you may check the code above (sorry for the messy code), but how can I calculate all those in O(S^2)? I mean, just calculating all these out forcely is O(S^3).

Comment: @newbie why are you computing all cells of sel? It seems you need only some of them - for a fixed n.

Comment: Just curious you might suppose :) The problem itself really does need all the cells.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125322/discussion-between-newbie-and-ivaylo-strandjev).